# How to choose starting Activity based on condition

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I have 4 radio buttons like below and i want to select only 1 out of any 4 choices and also one time after that user can't go back to change the choices he filled.......and when the app opens user should be directed to the activity filled by his choice. How should i do that?
Thank you.

```
RadioButton FourthGrade = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.grade_4th);


            FourthGrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CourseSelectionActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can preselect the radio button of choice when you will come on that activity. Make sure while coming back to this activity you have saved this user choise in your DB/ Shared Pref. 
Also, after user selects any choice you can disable the radio group.

Comment: use `RadioGroup` and `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "navigator" `Activity` as an entry point to your app, something like this:

```
public class NavigatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY_CHOICE = "choice";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // fetch the choice of the user, or return -1 if there is no choice yet
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int choice = prefs.getInt(KEY_CHOICE, -1);
        Intent intent = createIntentBasedOnChoice(this, choice);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // this method returns an Intent based on the passed choice parameter
    public static Intent createIntentBasedOnChoice(Context context, int choice) {
        Intent intent;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                intent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                intent = new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                intent = new Intent(context, FourthActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // if there is no choice yet, start the ChoiceActivity
                intent = new Intent(context, ChoiceActivity.class);
                break;
            }
        }
        return intent;
    }
}
```

This would navigate to one of the four activities depending on the user's preceding choice. If the user has not chosen yet, it will navigate to `ChoiceActivity`.

A basic layout for `ChoiceActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/group_choices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Choice 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choice 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choice 3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_choice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choice 4" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my choice!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And its code would look something like this:

```
public class ChoiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choice);

        final RadioGroup choiceGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(
            R.id.group_choices);
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int choice;

                switch (choiceGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                    case R.id.button_choice1: {
                        choice = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.button_choice2: {
                        choice = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.button_choice3: {
                        choice = 3;
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.button_choice4: {
                        choice = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        choice = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // saving the choice of the user
                PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChoiceActivity.this)
                    .edit()
                    .putInt(NavigatorActivity.KEY_CHOICE, choice)
                    .apply();

                Intent intent = NavigatorActivity
                    .createIntentBasedOnChoice(ChoiceActivity.this, choice);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will save the user's choice in `SharedPreferences` and navigate forward to the appropriate `Activity`.

This is just a very basic example to get you going, tailor it according to your needs.